# Rospy subscriber calling only one thread

Tags: ros, rospy, rosservice, thread, msg-subscriber

I am using python for programming the scripts in my ROS package, for a project. As part of the project, I need to implement a service client, which also subscribes to a topic. Specifically, the node subscribes and receives Pose information, and uses ROS services to perform navigation for an AMR. For the purposes of the project, it is not possible to use any other means of navigation, than using the services. The problem is, that after the service calls, the next thread begins, and a new service is called, even though the previous execution has not finished. I considered keeping the service calls in a while loop, and using rospy.sleep(), however that seems to be a very ugly solution, and it would also potentially block the execution of the service. Any info on starting a single subscriber thread is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) for better explaining the issue.